# 7 lines of code won't work... Unhandled exception at 0x76F643D2 in Conv.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x008EDDD8

Tags: c++, opencv

```
Mat oImg, test;
test = imread(fileName, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);

Mat gray;
//cvtColor(gray, test, CV_RGB2GRAY);
gray = test.clone();

adaptiveThreshold(oImg, gray, 255, ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, CV_THRESH_BINARY, 7, 15);

cv::imshow("original", gray);
cv::imshow("gaussian", oImg);
```

This is giving me following error:

```
Unhandled exception... cv::Exception at memory location 0x008EDDD8.
```

I have no clue what I'm doing wrong.. This has took me way too much time any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Where is `oImg` initialized?

Answer (score 1):

Code taken from your example (with minor code changes).

```
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
     cv::Mat oImg, test;
     test = cv::imread("Snap.JPG", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);

     cv::Mat gray;
     gray = test.clone();

     oImg = gray.clone();    // You need to do this to allocate space for oImg

     if (oImg.data == gray.data)
         std::cout << "Points to data stored in gray\n";
     else
         std::cout << "oImg has its own copy of data\n";

     adaptiveThreshold(oImg, gray, 255, cv::ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, CV_THRESH_BINARY, 7, 15);

     cv::imshow("original", gray);
     cv::imshow("gaussian", oImg);

     cv::waitKey(0);
     cv::destroyAllWindows();

     return 0;
}
```

You need to understand how `Mat` object works, details [here](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/core/mat_the_basic_image_container/mat_the_basic_image_container.html).